# OnAreaTouched stacking Andengine

Tags: touch, andengine, sprite

First I will show you image to explain my problem

> [image: Small unScaled Image]

**Description of image:**

I have 2 sprites **RED** and **white** .I attached

1. Red Sprite with Scene   and
2. White Sprite with Red Sprite

I have moved and scaled it **Red Sprite** and **white sprite** like in 2nd image

[image: Scaled Moved Image]

**My Problem**

I have registered touch listener.But **I want to register touch of white sprite when full image is scaled (after 2nd image case)**

**But when i register touch on fully scale it doesn't trigger touch .**

To trigger touch i have to register both sprites touch before **image 1**

**I have also seen similar problem** [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61079/andengine-onareatouched) .

My code

```
> `titleScene = new Scene();
        titleScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 1, 0));
        A_Background_Sprite = new Sprite(0, 0, A_Background_TextureRegion, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        titleScene.attachChild(A_Background_Sprite);
        RED_Sprite = new Sprite(50, 50, RED_TextureRegion, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){


            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                if(!RED_Sprite.isScaled())

                {
                Log.i("Apple_Background_Sprite", "setOnClickListener");
                AppleX=(int) RED_Sprite.getX();

                AppleY= (int) RED_Sprite.getY();



                RED_Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(1f, RED_Sprite.getX(), camera.getCenterX(), RED_Sprite.getY(),camera.getCenterY()),new ScaleModifier(1f, 1f, 2f, new IEntityModifierListener() {

                    public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        white_Sprite.setVisible(true);
        titleScene.registerTouchArea(white_Sprite);
                    }

                    public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    }
                },EaseLinear.getInstance())));




                }
                else
                {        

                //  Spelling_Background_Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(4f,  camera.getWidth(), 20, 400, 400));

                }

                return true;
                              // here you can use the code
                            }
        };



        RED_Sprite.setSize(150f, 150f);


        titleScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

        white_Sprite.setVisible(false);

        titleScene.attachChild(RED_Sprite);
        RED_Sprite.attachChild(white_Sprite);


        titleScene.registerTouchArea(RED_Sprite);
```

PLease Take a look at

RED_Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(1f, RED_Sprite.getX(), camera.getCenterX(), RED_Sprite.getY(),camera.getCenterY()),new ScaleModifier(1f, 1f, 2f, new IEntityModifierListener() {

```
            public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                white_Sprite.setVisible(true);
titleScene.registerTouchArea(white_Sprite);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have overlying objects, and you want to trigger touch events on all of them, be sure you don't return true at the end of the onTouch callback function, otherwise the touch listener stops processing the remaining touch events. See this tutorial for more info http://andengineguides.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/getting-started-touch-events/